# Error creating nested directories on Android with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, html5-filesystem, cordova-3

Problem is that I can not create a nested directory structure in Android with the following code under Cordova 3.0 on Android 4.3. (same code works in iOs)

```
var createDirectories = function(directoryArray, currentDir) {
    var parent = currentDir;
    var create = function(dirs) {
        if (dirs.length > 0) {
            console.log('Creating dir: ' + parent.fullPath + '/' + dirs[0]);
            parent.getDirectory(dirs[0], {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(newDir){
                console.log('Directory created: ' + newDir.fullPath);
                parent = newDir;
                dirs.splice(0, 1);
                create(dirs);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('Error creating directory. ' + err.code);
                console.log(err);
                if (FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR === err.code) {
                    console.log('Directory already exists.');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    };
    create(directoryArray);
};
```

No matter what I have tried the call fails with the PATH_EXISTS_ERR. So if I pass ['images','test'] in it will create 'images', but fail on 'test'. As anyone run into this problem before?

On iOs I get 2 'Directory created: ...' outputs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Arg, seems to be that there is an 'images' file, or it is at least a special name in Android. Adding some debugging to the FileUtils plugin I found that 'images' already exists, but is not a directory, and the error's are not clear enough to determine that.

So, solution is to not use 'images' as a new directory in the root of your apps filesystem on Android.